# protocol-buffers serialization with large list of non-primitive types

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am switching some of my DataContractSerializer usage over to protocol-buffers serialization (specifically using protobuf-net) with the goal of faster serialization and smaller serialized data size for storing in a database blob.

I found that changing my object model has a big impact on the message size. I take this to mean that my serialized data is being artificially inflated due to my choice of object model, and I'd like to fix that.

Specifically my question is: could I change my protobuf-net usage, or possibly serialization library, to get a smaller message size?  I'll give an object model and what I have been able to figure out so far below.

In my case I'm serializing OCR data... here is a simplified object model:

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true, UseProtoMembersOnly = true)]
public class OcrTable
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]        
    public List<OcrTableCell> Cells;
}

[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true, UseProtoMembersOnly = true)]
public class OcrTableCell
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Row;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Column;
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public int RowSpan;

    //...

    [ProtoMember(10)]
    public int Height;

    [ProtoMember(11)]
    public List<OcrCharacter> Characters;
}

[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true, UseProtoMembersOnly = true)]
public class OcrCharacter
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Code;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Data;
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public int Confidence;

    //...

    [ProtoMember(11)]
    public int Width;
}
```

Since the data is ultimately just a bunch of associated primitives (mostly `int`'s), I assume the benefits of packed-bits serialization would be helpful, but in the current class structure, all the actual lists are of custom types.

To allow for packed bits serialization, I tinkered with dropping the custom types altogether, and having multiple lists of primitives, correlated by their sequence. For example:

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true, UseProtoMembersOnly = true)]
public class OcrTableCell
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Row;

    //...

    [ProtoMember(10)]
    public int Height;

    [ProtoMember(11, IsPacked=true)]
    public List<int> CharacterCode;

    [ProtoMember(12, IsPacked=true)]
    public List<int> CharacterData;

    //...

    [ProtoMember(21, IsPacked=true)]
    public List<int> CharacterWidth;
}
```

Here you can see I replaced `List<OcrCharacter>` with multiple lists: one for each field in `OcrCharacter`.  This has a fairly large impact on serialized data size, in some cases reducing by two-thirds (even after gzipping).

I don't think its practical to make changes like these to my object model just to support serialization ... and keeping a second "helper" model to prepare for serialization seems undesirable.

Still it bugs me that I have an artificially inflated serialized data size just because of the object model for the data.

Is there a better choice of serialization parameters or library to serialize this type of object graph?  I did try setting `DataFormat=DataFormat.Group` on the `ProtoMember` attributes applied to lists, but saw 0 change in the message size which confused me.

Comment: I confess, I'm intrigued - it isn't impossible to write some kind of automatic transposer, mapping properties by index to "packed" elements by position. Can I think more on this and get back to you?

Comment: For `OcrCharacter` I suspect I can get it working - basically, the rule would be "to enable packed transposition, all the members on the type must be of the same type, and that type must be a primitive that is compatible with packed encoding; the field-number specified on the field would map to the 1-based position in the transposed sequence" - does that sound reasonable? I'm also tempted to add "field numbers of the members must be contiguous". This would all seem to describe your `OcrCharacter` type quite well. Thoughts?

Comment: Also: it would need to be elective (opt-in) - maybe some new `TransposePacked=true` on the `[ProtoContract]`… would that work?

Comment: Heck yes that would work :) glad you're intrigued.  I didn't think it was too pie-in-the-sky of an idea ... was thinking surely people serialize a lot of integer `Point` objects or similar. Depending on the data (like in my case) the packed bits encoding has just outstanding performance (lots of runs in the data) and I hated to miss out on it.

Comment: As for the type restrictions, you would know what is required for the implementation you have in mind. I was thinking the containing class would essentially pick up one list per field of the original class... that should maximize likelihood of runs hence maximum packed bits benefit. But then not sure why they would need to be of similar type, or even a primitive type (some types wouldn't be packed, but oh well). If I were to implement it manually this is what I had in mind. You might have something very different in mind, and indeed the restrictions you mention would work in my case.

Comment: I just implemented the "one list for every field" idea and used some more robust testing data. Didn't see quite as dramatic a result as my initial testing ... still though a 15% decrease (70K reduced to 59.4K per page), and surprisingly a 25% decrease in gzipped sizes (25.7K to 19.3K). Not sure why using packedbits makes gzip more effective...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inside protobuf-net that is going to magiacally rearrange your object model to exploit specific features; that requires detailed knowledge of the data, which is something that is obvious to a human but pretty hard to generalize. Without investing significant time, the answer here is simply: it is going to serialize it *as it is laid out in the model* - and if that isn't the perfect scenario: so be it.

As for the `Group` data-format not helping: grouped sub-messages only applies to things like `List<OcrCharacter>`; since the field-number is `11`, it guarantees to need 2 bytes overhead: 1 byte for the start-group marker, one byte for the end-group marker. The alternative is length-prefixed, which will need 1 byte for the field-header, and a ***variable*** number of bytes for the length of the sub-message, encoded as a `varint`. If each sub-message is less than 128 bytes, this will still only require one byte to encode the length (so 2 bytes overall) - which is probably why it isn't making any difference: each individual `OcrCharacter` is small enough (less than 128 bytes) that `Group` can't help.

Comment: Thanks for the `Group` explanation, that makes good sense. Also this answers my question about available options in protocol-buffers (and protobuf-net). I agree that a serializer can't know which optimizations are perfect without domain knowledge or some fancy heuristics, but it could expose a few options. I think of this case as the serializer just changing how it stores pretty simple structured data, which is comparable to existing reference tracking or packedbits options.